# How can i install NetHunter on Ubuntu 16.04?

Tags: kali

I know Kali made it but i think it should be possible to install it on Ubuntu as well. Anyone could help? Thanks in advance!

Answer (score 0, accepted):

no , its an android rom image that does custom things with the hardware to deploy its exploits.

you might be able to get it to boot via an android emulator but you probably will be missing the hardware it needs to work its magic.

Heres how to run roms via adb, make sure you select the right device to emulate for the rom image you download.
http://forum.xda-developers.com/showthread.php?t=1599005

Comment: so what's relative software of nethunter on Ubuntu or Kali?

Comment: you could try the metasploit framework - https://github.com/rapid7/metasploit-framework/wiki/Nightly-Installers